# How to manage my node version using Fish Shell

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, terminal

I started using fish as my shell yesterday, and today I tried to run my NextJs App in the terminal using yarn and tailwind gave me an error about the node version. I checked it, and then I noticed that the current version was 10.19.0.

In my zsh shell, I have node, npm and nvm installed, and I can use them without any errors, but in my fish shell, only node is present. I tried to install nvm in the terminal with this command:

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.4/install.sh | bash
```

and the following output was:

```
=> nvm is already installed in /home/gabriel/.nvm, trying to update using git
=> error: pathspec 'v0.31.4' did not match any file(s) known to git

=> Source string already in /home/gabriel/.profile
main: linha 293: /nvm.sh: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="/home/gabriel/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm⏎
```

The last instruction gives me commands I can use to run nvm, but when I run them, I get an error

Commands given

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/gabriel/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Output

```
~/.nvm/nvm.sh (line 942): Unexpected ')' found, expecting '}'
      "${NVM_NODE_PREFIX}")
                          ^
from sourcing file ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        called on line 185 of file /usr/share/fish/config.fish
in function '.' with arguments '/home/gabriel/.nvm/nvm.sh'
source: Error while reading file “/home/gabriel/.nvm/nvm.sh”
```

Comment: fish is not POSIX compliant.. Which means nvm cannot support it.. [check out this tutorial](https://eshlox.net/2019/01/27/how-to-use-nvm-with-fish-shell) to circumvent and run nvm

Answer (score 11):

So, I found two ways,

One is using *nvm* with only bash. Whenever you need to use *nvm* command, use **bash**. Then go back to **fish** and do all the node relates stuffs, change **nvm use [version]** in bash. Then work in fish and still it will use the version NVM sets.

Another is, install curl, install fisher, install bass plugin to support bash style in fish,

`sudo apt install curl`

`curl -sL https://git.io/fisher | source && fisher install jorgebucaran/fisher`

`fisher install edc/bass`

Create **nvm.fish**
`sudo nano ~/.config/fish/functions/nvm.fish`

Add this code to the file nvm.fish

```
function nvm
    bass source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh --no-use ';' nvm $argv
end
```

Now, you can use *nvm* command in Fish

Comment: Based on your answer, I changed `nvm.fish` to `bash -c "source ~/.bash_nvm && nvm $argv && fish"` while `.bash_nvm` contains the nvm setup for bash. Might have other downsides I am not aware of, but does not require any additional dependencies.

Comment: the bass method worked!